# Scroll area too small with SectionList React Native

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, mobile, react-native-sectionlist

I am currently trying to use a `<SectionList>` inside a classic `<View>`, all my datas are formatted, the list displays correctly and my item's actions are working.

The issue is that when I am on the top of my SectionList, the area available to trigger the scroll is actually really small ( roughly 100 pixels from the top of the list ). However, once i scroll down a bit from that area, the whole list becomes scrollable and works as intended until I scroll back to the top.

My parent View has `flex: 1` as well as my SectionList

**Environment**
Working environment : MacOS Sierra 10.13.3
Expo version : 23.0
React Native version : 0.50
React : 16.0
Using an IPhone 8 simulation
There's no issue on Android

**Steps to Reproduce**
Classic creation of a SectionList inside of a View

**Expected Behavior**
The scroll must be triggered from everywhere in the SectionList

**Actual Behavior**
When the SectionList is at the top, the scroll only triggers inside a small area ( around 100px from the top of the list )

The code of my SectionList :

```
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <SectionList
        style={styles.openSectionList} // flex: 1
        scrollEnabled
        stickySectionHeadersEnabled
        sections={this.sections}
        keyExtractor={item => item["@id"]}
        removeClippedSubviews
        renderSectionHeader={({ section }) => (
          <TouchableHighlight
            onPress={() => this.onSectionHeaderPressRef(section.index)}
            activeOpacity={0.65}
            underlayColor="rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2)"
            style={styles.sectionHeader}
          >
            <View style={styles.categoryContentContainer}>
              <View style={styles.firstPartContent}>
                <Text style={styles.categoryHeaderText}>
                  {section.title === "Autres"
                    ? "Mes produits"
                    : section.title}{" "}
                </Text>
                {section.nbItems - section.nbItemsSelected === 0 ? (
                  <CheckBox
                    label=""
                    checked
                    checkboxStyle={styles.checkbox}
                    checkboxContainer={styles.checkboxContainer}
                  />
                ) : (
                  <Text
                    style={[
                      styles.categoryHeaderText,
                      { color: Colors.contrastColor },
                    ]}
                  >
                    ({section.nbItems - section.nbItemsSelected})
                  </Text>
                )}
              </View>
              <Image
                source={require("../../../assets/common/chevron.png")}
                style={
                  section.index === this.state.currentCategoryOpen
                    ? styles.categoryChevronOpen
                    : styles.categoryChevronClosed
                }
              />
            </View>
          </TouchableHighlight>
        )}
        renderItem={({ item }) =>
          this.state.currentCategoryOpen === item.categoryIndex ? (
            <ShoppingListProduct
              key={item["@id"]}
              ingredient={item}
              updateIngredient={this.updateIngredientListRef}
              onLongPress={this.itemLongPressedRef}
            />
          ) : null}
      />
  </View>
```

A GIF of the actual behavior ( I'm trying to scroll everytime the cursor is moving ) where we can see that the scroll only triggers when I am above a certain height.

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9jVwJ.gif)

Any help would be appreciated as I don't know if that's a bug and/or me implementing the component wrong.

Thank you by advance.

Comment: Did you find the solution to this?

Comment: @Lazy I had the same or a very similar issue. This bug was only on iOS, Android was working perfectly. After a lot of trial and error I found out that a (likely) culprit was actually `stickySectionHeadersEnabled`. When set to `false` everything is working. Keep in mind it is enabled by default on iOS. I'll try to prepare a minimal repro.

Comment: @Clonescody do you have a minimal working example of this bug somewhere? Maybe on https://snack.expo.io?

Comment: @szalski No unfortunately, this was an old version of my app and we reworked everything a few months ago.

Sorry for late reply, hope you can correct your issue

Answer (score 0):

someone asked me the solution for this via email so I might as well add it here, from what i remember it was a position/imbrication problem with the  components.

I can't remember exactly but I ended up with this code ( my page content changes so that's why it is set as a variable )

```
// render method

component = ( <SectionList
     style={styles.openSectionList} // flex: 1, height: "100%"
     scrollEnabled
     stickySectionHeadersEnabled
     sections={this.sections}
     bounces={false}
     keyExtractor={item =>
         item["@id"] === undefined ? item.userIngredient : item["@id"]
     }
     getItemLayout={this.getItemLayout}
     renderSectionHeader={this.renderSectionListHeaderRef}
     renderItem={this.renderSectionListItemRef}
 /> )

 return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            {component}
        </View>
 )
```

So yeah watch out where your SectionList is defined and how many parents it has, I think it required only one

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix mine by adding this prop to the section list
`stickySectionHeadersEnabled={false}`

Answer (score -1):

I added a `marginBottom` to the `SectionList` of equal amount of space consumed by the `View` on top to equalise the area.